# jruby on rails app and warbler, tomcat, windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, tomcat7, warbler

I have a **JRuby Rails** app. It runs with **"rails s app"**. 
With warbler I have built a war-file and integrated it with the tomcat. 
The app starts, but then I get an error message:

> "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

In the log file, the following is displayed:

> "INFO: F, [2016-12-14T11: 06: 40.187000 # 124] FATAL -:
>   ActionView :: Template :: Error (undefined: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined)):
>         7:
>         8: .row
>         9: .col-md-6
>        10: = image_tag 'leaman_ir_doc.png', style: "width: 100%, border: 2px solid gray;"
>        11:
>      App / views / home / index.html.haml: 10: in `_app_views_home_index_html_haml__819972750_6656 '"

I do not know where the SyntaxError comes from !?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the images and stylsheets are not found. If I leave in the development.rb or production.rb under config following entry away, then runs the application error-free:
Config.assets.js_compressor =: uglifier
Does anyone know why with this setting the images and stylsheets are no longer found and what I can do about it?

Thanks for any answer :-)